# ArcGis Esri Custom Popup

Tags: vue.js, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am using Vue.js for my web application. I created a custom html popup element and tried to add it to the UI (on top of the house icon which you can see in the example), but I cannot make it appear on coordinates which are clicked. I know that I can do it with adding to the view UI and setting position to "manual", but I couldn't find any examples of setting the specific coordinates. Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
  this.viewt.ui.add(document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0], {position: "manual"});
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpzQN.jpg)

Template code

```html
<template>
<div class="popup" v-if="openPopUp" ref="popupwindow">
        <article class="house-card" id="popup-test">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img class="post-image"
                 src="https://www.comitatoaurora.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/contemporary-exterior.jpg"/>
            <div class="middle">
              €{{ Math.round(this.object.Price) }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="article-details" :key="this.object.Address" @mouseover="hover = true"
               @mouseleave="hover = false">

            <div class="post-category">
              <div>
                {{
                  this.object.Address.replace(this.object.Address.substring(this.object.Address.indexOf(','),
                      this.object.Address.indexOf(',') + 9), ', ')
                }}<span
                  style="margin: 0.3vw"></span>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="percentage-circle">
              <div class="progress-single">
                <v-progress-circular
                    color="rgba(81, 87, 102, 0.99)"
                    :size="30"
                    :width="2"
                    :value="this.object.Risk"
                >{{ this.object.Risk }}
                </v-progress-circular>
                <div class="progress-text">
                  <p>Risk</p>
                  <p>Score</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="progress-single">
                <v-progress-circular
                    color="rgba(81, 87, 102, 0.99)"
                    :size="30"
                    :width="2"
                    :value="this.object.Gross_rental_yield*10"
                >{{
                    Math.round((this.object.Gross_rental_yield +
                        Number.EPSILON) * 10) / 10
                  }}
                </v-progress-circular>
                <div class="progress-text">
                  <p>Gross</p>
                  <p>Yield</p>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="progress-single">
                <v-progress-circular
                    color="rgba(81, 87, 102, 0.99)"
                    :size="30"
                    :width="2"
                    :value="this.object.Net_yield*100/5"
                >{{ Math.round((this.object.Net_yield + Number.EPSILON) * 10) / 10 }}
                </v-progress-circular>
                <div class="progress-text">
                  <p>Net</p>
                  <p>Yield</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="percentage-circle metrics-level">
              <div class="bottom-metric"><img height="12vh"
                                              src="../../public/img/year.svg"
                                              alt="year"/><b>{{
                  this.object.ConstructionYear
                }} </b></div>
              <div class="headerDivider"></div>

              <div class="bottom-metric"><img height="12vh"
                                              src="../../public/img/rent.svg"
                                              alt="rent"/><b>{{ this.object.Estimated_Rent }}€/mo</b>
              </div>
              <div class="headerDivider"></div>
              <div class="bottom-metric" style="margin-left: 0.15vw !important;"><img height="12vh"
                                                                                      src="../../public/img/square.svg"
                                                                                      alt="square"/>
                <b>{{ this.object.Sqm }}m<sup>2</sup></b></div>
            </div>
            <transition name="fadeo">
              <div v-if="hover" class="overlay">
                <router-link :to="{name:'card', params: { id: this.id }}">
                  <div class="overlay-text"> View Asset</div>
                </router-link>
              </div>
            </transition>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      </template>
```

Comment: That is weird, can you add the popup template code?, and how are you adding it to the layer?.

Comment: yes i added template code to the initial question

Comment: I am creating the MapView and trying to add an element to its UI since it's completely custom

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for popup to open over a selected feature,

1. automatically, for example when a feature is selected,
2. manually, using popup `open` method.

If you opted for 1), you have to set the PopupTemplate for the layer or the graphic. You have a couple of ways to define custom content for the `PopupTemplate`, like using a funtion or a promise.

[ArcGIS API - PopupTemplate content](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#content)

If you opted for 2), then you need to,

1. disable the default behavior if the view (auto open to false),
2. listen for click events,
3. on every click event manually open the popup (if a feature was selected), with the map point of the click event as location

```
view.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false; // <- disable view popup auto open
view.on("click", function (event) { // <- listen to view click event
  if (event.button === 0) { // <- check that was left button or touch
    view.popup.open({ // <- open popup
      location: event.mapPoint, // <- use map point of the click event
      fetchFeatures: true // <- fetch the selected features (if any)
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: the thing is, my popup is added as a regular html element, not a popUpTemplate, since creating it just using a 'content' field offers too limited styling options. So using 'view.popup.open' will not work here. i am looking for basically the same function but to add HTMLElement

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. I see .. So I think you have a number of options, i) you could keep esri popup and use your content, ii) you could take the screen position from the click and float your custom popup to display accordingly, iii) mark the selected feature on the map and display your content in a fixed position .. I think i) and iii) are good possibilities and easy to implement, ii) would depend on your how versatile is you popup component

Comment: Thank you I think an idea with screen position will work for me!

Comment: Adding this line solved my problem (view.popup.open wasn't creating the popup) - many thanks cabesuon:   view.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false;